# DC/DC Converter MOSFET switching

Tags: mosfet, pwm, dc-dc-converter, sepic

I am currently building a SEPIC converter. The signal arriving from the MOSFET driver to the MOSFET seems all good, however the Vds doesn't seem to follow the drivers signal and it makes the MOSFET conduct most of the time, therefore shorting the circuit. Anybody knows how to make this work properly?

Note: there is no load connected, Vin = 4 - 8V, Vout should be 12.5V, PWN circuit (PIC) is powered by a 12V supply

Thank you![image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there anything actively turning the MOSFET OFF (quickly) or is it left hanging to discharge? Without the circuit as Andy says - we need a psychic (+1).

Comment: Why use a Sepic at all? Since Vin < Vout a boost could be used, which would be much more simple.

Comment: The circuit is just the same as any other SEPIC converter schematic, one probe is at the MOSFET gate(square wave), the other one is at the drain. I am using a SEPIC because sometimes Vout<Vin. There is a driver TC1411N that is in charge of turning the MOSFET on and off, I assume this driver will have an internal Rg to discharge the gate.

Comment: Still need a schematic. There's a standard power topology for a sepic, but your gate drive could be literally anything, and that's probably where a problem like this is coming from. Could be miller effect, for example, the drain being pulled high rapidly could turn the transistor back on. Especially if you don't have a resistor and capacitor from gate to source. But we have no way of knowing that without a schematic.

Comment: Okay schematics have been attached. I have actually fixed the problem. Through a LTSpice sim I realized that the inductors values were too low, and the voltage was rising to very high levels when the circuit had no load. I've changed the inductors to 220uH and the Fsw to 200KHz and the supply seems more stable, although there are some miss matches between the theoretical value of Vout for a given D. Seems like I have to introduce a correction factor via software.

Comment: In the driver's datasheet it mention that it has an output capacitance of 1000pF, however the MOSFET has an input capacitance of 5000pF, would this be a problem?